# Dataframe with specific column names cannot dot product with series/dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dot-product

When I am trying to have a 3*5 dataframe x [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l62TE.png) dot product with a 5*1 series [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fhsX.png), it gives an error 'Matrices are not aligned'. The dimensions shouldn't be a problem here when doing the dot product (3*5 dot 5*1 should produce me a 3*1 series), and I have checked the source code for dot product. Seems Python tried to union the column names [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwriQ.png) of the dataframe with the index of the series, and in my case, obvious they cannot be aligned and thus dimensions wouldn't match. I have to rename the columns to index-like features 0,1,2... so that they could be aligned with the index of the series. But I wonder if there is any better way to do this? What if I have 1000 columns in the dataframe with pre-set names, should I still try to convert these names into integers first? Why does Python deal with dot product that way?

Comment: You need to use numpy

Comment: use df.values to extract numpy ndarray and do dot multiplication

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',header=None)
df1
0   1   2   3   4
0   12  0   0   0   0
1   12  0   0   0   0
2   12  0   0   0   0

df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',header=None)
df2
0
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   1
4   5

import numpy as np

np.dot(df1.values,df2.values)
array([[12],
       [12],
       [12]])
```